# Using Integration by Parts to relate/show the same relationship

Tags: calculus

The problem I have says to: relate Γ(n + 1) to Γ(n)

In other words I need to show that Γ(n+1) = nΓ(n)

I know we use the    ∫ u(dv) = u(v) - ∫ v(du)  to do integration by parts but then how could I do that with gamma Γ

Comment: What is your definition of gamma function?

Answer (score 0):

Let me remind us that for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\textrm{Re}(z)>0$, one has:
$$\Gamma(z):=\int_0^{+\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$
This integral is convergent, since $\displaystyle |t^{z-1}e^{-t}|=t^{\textrm{Re}(z)-1}e^{-t}=o\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)$. Furthermore, the function involved are smooth. Therefore, one can do integration by parts:
$$\Gamma(z+1)=\int_0^{+\infty}t^ze^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t=[-t^ze^{-t}]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}+\int_0^{+\infty}zt^{z-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t=z\Gamma(z).$$
Whence the result.